# Implementation method Throws exception but interface method don't define as it throws exception

Tags: java, exception, jls

when implementing an interface, it's perfectly legal for the interface methods not to throw an exception, but the implementation class method can throw Exception.

Interface definition

```
public interface exceptionNotDefined {
    void doNotThrowException();
}
```

Implementing class

```
public class exceptionNotDefinedImpl implements exceptionNotDefined {
    @Override
    public void doNotThrowException() throws RuntimeException{

    }
}
```

what's the logic behind this, and what part of the Java Language Specification deals with this.

Comment: FYI : RunTimeException(s) need not be explicitly defined as `throws`. Only checked exceptions should be.

Comment: @T.J - s/should be/have to be/p.  It can be beneficial to use `throws` for unchecked exceptions.  It can aid in documenting the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... what's the logic behind this

The logic is best described by the word "substitutability".

When an interface method is declared as "throwing" a *checked* exception, it is saying that the caller has to deal with the exception (by catching it or by declaring it ... or a supertype).

When you then implement the method without throwing the exception, the method call is substitutable.  A caller which has code to deal with the possibility of the exception can cope if the exception won't be thrown.

The other wrinkle is that in the implementing class you declared the method as throwing `RuntimeException`.  `RuntimeException` and its subclasses are *unchecked* exceptions, and the Java language says that a caller *doesn't need to* deal with unchecked exceptions.  So, in fact, the `throws RuntimeException` has no practical effect, except for documenting the API designer's intent.

---

> ... what part of the Java Language Specification deals with this.

JLS Section [11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) covers most of this at a high level, and the specific rules about method overriding (including `throws` clauses) are given in JLS [8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).